# Should users be forced to word their title as a question?

Tags: discussion

I see a lot of "questions" where the title isn't phrased like a question. They won't start with a question like should, what, when, where, did, etc.

Titles as questions tend to be more descriptive.

Let's take this arbitrary example:

> Convert linkedin timestamp to MySQL datetime

Ok. Convert things to stuff, right. Wait, what about it? Do you want to know how to do it? Do you have code to do it that's not working? Are you trying to find a better way?

Now if you were to ask a question, it would hopefully be one of these:

> How do I ... (although many people probably use this for the latter
>   two as well) 
>   How can I fix my code to ... 
>   Is there a better way to ...

Much better.

Should users be forced to word their title as a question?

Note: my question is different from the possible duplicate in that the possible duplicate asks about a particular user editing certain questions and the answers focus on that. My question focuses more on the general aspect of phrasing titles as questions.

Comment: Why should they?

Comment: @Servy that's the question.

Comment: How would you enforce this? Every single question that gets asked gets put into review queue? Mandatory question mark? Neither of those solutions seem viable at all.

Comment: So why are you asking it?  You're implying that they shouldn't.  If you want people to be required to, then justify that position.  If you don't care, then why ask in the first place?

Comment: @tnw, if the first word of the question isn't a question word, then flag it.

Comment: `Convert linkedin timestamp to MySQL datetime`. Would changing this into a question create a better title? `How do I convert a LinkedIn Timestamp to a MySQL DateTime`?`. Does that actually make it any clearer than it was? Does it matter? I don't think it does.

Comment: @SupremeGrandRuler Titles should just be basic summaries of the problem. Arbitrarily requiring that they be questions doesn't add any more useful information and is just a hassle.

Comment: No, we shouldn't force users to do anything that's essentially just a style preference. IIRC, there was a blog post about how question titles phrased as questions have a greater chance of being answered but that's not a good reason to require it.

Comment: *Is there a better way to* - "better" is subjective and my understanding is that Code Review is a better place to discuss working code you want to improve.

Comment: @SupremeGrandRuler "I have some code for algo X. How do I make it better?" My title IS a question and your algo would catch it as not one, requiring me to change my "I" for a question word. How does that make sense? (not saying that title is GOOD. Just showing an example of a title that can be a question and not start with a "question word".)

Answer (score 6):

> Should users be forced to word their title as a question?

No, they shouldn't. Such a measure would only annoy those who write good titles regardless of whether they are explicitly phrased as questions, while not preventing bad titles that happen to be explicit questions -- cf. ["How do I fix my code?"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22How+do+I+fix+my+code%3F%22), ["What is wrong?'](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22What+is+wrong%3F%22), etc.

Answer (score 3):

My answer: No they should not.

This will not improve the quality of a question - And there are TONS of low quality questions out there, so we should handle those first, before trying to force users to phrase the title as a question.